# How to join two collection result and another collection using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I tried join two collections output and one collections.but its not working how to join two collections results join to one coleection using mongodb

**promotion collection**

```
[{
    "id":1,
    "name":"latest",
    "product":[{
                 "id":3,
              }]

}]
```

**product collection**

```
[{
     "id":3,
     "product_name":"bourbon",
     "category_id": 18
}]
```

**Category Collection**

```
[{
   "id":10,
   "name":"laptop"
}]
```

**Mapping Code**

```
db.promotion.aggregate([{$lookup:{
            from:'product',
            localField:'products',
            foreignField:'id',
            as:'products'
        }}]).toArray()
```

**I Got Output**

```
[{
    "id":1,
    "name":"latest",
    "product":[{
                 "id":3,
                  "product_name":"bourbon",
                  "category_id": 18
              }]

}]
```

**Excepted output**

```
[{
    "id":1,
    "name":"latest",
    "product":[{
                 "id":3,
                  "product_name":"bourbon",
                  "name":"laptop"
              }]

}]
```

How to achieve it.this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.promotion.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "product",
    "let": { "products": "$products" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$id", "$$products"] } } },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "category",
        "let": { "category_id": "$category_id" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$id", "$$category_id"] } } }
        ],
        "as": "category"
      }},
      { "$project": {
        "id": 1,
        "product_name": "bourbon",
        "name": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$category.name", 0] }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "product"
  }}
])
```

Comment: @ Fanpark .How to learn mongodb aggregation and pipeline framework can give some suggestion or any videos link

Comment: Sure I will update my question with the explanation

Comment: if u use mongose, u can use populate

Comment: Sorry  I uisng mongoclient